# Zend Framework: rendering view script based on switch statement, should I create a view helper to handle this?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Within one of my view scripts, I am showing a table of data for lets say, cars.  Based on the type of car (using a switch statement), I show a different image.  I do this in a couple different views, so I was wondering, should I be using a view helper to handle this so I don't duplicate the switch statement in multiple areas?  Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A view helper sounds the most appropriate, but you could potentially use a partial by itself... just passing in the value youre switiching.

Comment: I think partial clone View object for each call, so this can downgrade app speed, if it is used often.

Comment: I think youre right about that but it depends on what he needs back... if hes jsut changing the image name and can deal with getting a simple string back or just an image tag then thats fine (he can extend the TagHelper), but if its much more complex than that one would need to use a partial anyhow... Im kind of a Nazi about complex html strings being created in functions/methods. Id rather take the performance hit and then mitigate it later.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need modify those switch statements for each view, then view helper is good solution, because then if you need to do some changes, you do it only in one place.